# Console is still shown with WinMain entry point in C++ using Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, winmain

I'm trying to make a small application which starts another application depending on command line parameters.

I am using the `WinMain` entry point like this:

```
BOOL WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR commandLine, int nCmdShow) {
    ...
}
```

but I still see a console window.

How can I make sure that the no console window is ever drawn when running the application?

1. How to configure Netbeans in order to do so?
2. Do I have to change abovementioned code? If yes, what must be changed or added?

*PS: I can hide the console window with `ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE)`, but you still see the console window for a fraction of a second. I want to make sure that the console window is never shown.*

Comment: Visibility of the console window depends on the compiler parameters. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Flags in question are `-mconsole` and `-mwindows`. Those are analogs of [/SUBSYSTEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) flag of MSVC.

Comment: @Drop : I think it is the correct answer ... Why did you only post it as a comment ? :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is fine. The compiler flag `-mwindows` will do the trick.

To set the compiler flag do the following:

1. Right-click your project, click **Properties**
2. Click on **C++ Compiler** in the category **Build**
3. Add `-mwindows` in the line **Additional Options**
4. Click **OK** and rebuild your project.